# Change style of table data in hidden table row on reveal of table row

Tags: html, css, border, display

It's difficult to describe what I'm trying to do in the title, but basically I have a table with 9 cols, but one is display='none'.

Onclick of the row above, the hidden row becomes style='table-row'.

I have set the style of the 2nd TD to have a white background, 15px padding and and "red borders", successfully, but can't get the borders to 5px...

Here is (the important part of) my code:

CSS:

```
.formbg{
    padding: 15px;
    border: 5px;   /* This line is not rendering on the output.*/
    border-color: #c22034;
    background-color: white;
    display: table-data;
}
```

HTML

```
<tr class='toolboxrow'><td onclick='getForms()' ><img onclick='getForms()' src='image.jpg' /></td>
<td><span class='tbtext' onclick='getForms()' >Order Forms</span></td></tr>

<tr id='PersonalForms' style='display:none'><td></td>
<td class='formbg'>
<h3>Personalized Forms</h3> 
<form action='DrsPortal.php' method='post'>
<input class='onlineform' name='title' placeholder='Title'  />
<input class='onlineform' name='given' placeholder='Given Name' />
<input class='onlineform' name='surname' placeholder='Surname' /><br>
<input class='onlineformsubmit' type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
function getForms(){
    document.getElementById('PersonalForms').style.display='table-row'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the initial value "none" of the css property "border-style", border-width has no effect. Just use `border-style: solid` (or the shorthand property `border: 5px solid #c22034`) to render the border.